# Can Windows change your monitor's refresh rate?

Tags: windows, display, resolution

I have a 60Hz monitor with a native resolution of 1980 x 1080, so in Windows I have my resolution/refresh rate set to 1920x1080/60Hz as expected, but if you go to 'Display Adapter Properties' and then 'List All Modes', there are a wide range of resolutions and refresh rate combinations to choose from.

My question is, what happens if I set it to 1920x1080/30Hz? I understand the resolution part because that's being drawn in the computer so I can understand how Windows is able to control that, but the refresh rate is a property of the monitor, so if I set it to 30Hz, does Windows (or any OS for that matter) somehow communicate with the monitor and tell it to run at 30Hz?

I'm aware of EDID which monitors use to tell the OS what it is capable of displaying, is it anything related to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Does Windows (or any OS for that matter) communicate with the monitor and tell it to run at 30Hz?

The graphics card controls the refresh rate, and can overide EDID if instructed to do so.

Normally the settings in the graphics card's control panel are used select a particular refresh rate at any resolution as long as it's supported by both the graphics card and monitor.

If you select a higher refresh rate than those supported by the monitor then an 'Out of Frequency' error occurs resulting in a blank screen.

There are programs that can define custom resolutions/refresh rates. 
See [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](http://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) for one such program.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill but I still don't quite get it. I don't know exactly how it all works but surly it's some hardware/software in the monitor that tells it to go collect a new image from the GPU, so how is this controlled from the GPU? Doesn't something need to tell the monitor to collect a new image at 60Hz or 30Hz for example?

Comment: @RJSmith92 The graphics card tells the monitor to use a specified refresh rate. The monitor does what it's told or refuses to obey.

Comment: @RJSmith92 Monitors don't collect anything. Things are pushed to the monitor.

Comment: @RJSmith92 [How does a computer monitor work, OS-side?](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=83972&sid=0c86e15f0d17d3471f1386de2e5ebeaf)

Comment: Thanks for that, I don't know why I wrote the monitor collects the image, I know it doesn't.... Regarding the refresh rate, just to confirm, if I set my system to run at 1920 x 1080 @ 30Hz, the GPU would tell the monitor to only refresh at 30Hz? Is there some sort of standard for this, universal across most GPUs/monitors?

Comment: Yes. VGA, DVI, HDMI, etc ... read the link I just gave you ... ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32221/discussion-between-rjsmith92-and-davidpostill).

Comment: Hi David, sorry to bring this up again. Just quickly, when I said 'Is there some sort of standard for this, universal across most GPUs/monitors?' I didn't really mean standards like VGA and HDMI, I meant more of a protocol or something that OSs use to know how to tell the monitor to change it's refresh rate? It's just I've never read or heard of anything like that, I just wondered if there was a standard or protocol that is used?

Comment: @RJSmith92 The standard **includes** the protocol. For example "HDMI implements the EIA/CEA-861 standards, which define video formats and waveforms, transport of compressed, uncompressed, and LPCM audio, auxiliary data, and implementations of the VESA EDID. CEA-861 signals carried by HDMI are electrically compatible with the CEA-861 signals used by the digital visual interface (DVI). No signal conversion is necessary, nor is there a loss of video quality when a DVI-to-HDMI adapter is used" from [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI).

Comment: @RJSmith92 [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEA-861) is a data structure provided by a digital display to describe its capabilities to a video source (e.g. graphics card or set-top box). It is what enables a modern personal computer to know what kinds of monitors are connected to it. EDID is defined by a standard published by the Video Electronics Standards Association (VESA). The EDID includes manufacturer name and serial number, product type, phosphor or filter type, timings supported by the display, display size, luminance data and (for digital displays only) pixel mapping data.

Comment: @RJSmith92 You need to **read** the standards.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, I appreciate that but I haven't had time to read and scour the standards for the tiny bit of info I'm looking for. The EDID sounds like the GPU just reads info from the monitor to learn of it's capabilities, I haven't seen a bit yet where it says it can actually configure the monitor (as in set the monitors refresh rate). Thanks again.

Comment: I already told you. The graphics driver sends the appropriate commands to the video card  which sends the appropriate data to the monitor. You would need to look at the source code for the graphics driver to see exactly how this is done. Any more detail is outside the scope of your question as it makes it too broad. How to program a graphics driver or call its API is off-topic for [SU]

Comment: Alright thanks @DavidPostill I'll leave it there, but my point was if most/all GPUs can change the refresh rate of most/all monitors, there must be a standard to do this, which could be EDID, but I have yet to read anything that clearly says that EDID can be used to alter a monitors refresh rate.

Comment: @RJSmith92 It will be in one of the standards, I just don't know which one :/